# Start task without waiting

Tags: vb.net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I would like to start a background task without using the `Await` keyword.  Instead I want to monitor the task at various points and restart it when necessary to update information in the background.  Here is the method I am trying to call:

```
    Public Async Function UpdateVehicleSummaries(p_vehicleID As Int32) As Task(Of Boolean)
        Dim tempVehicle As Koolsoft.MARS.BusinessObjects.Vehicle
        For Each tempVehicle In Vehicles
            If p_vehicleID = 0 Or p_vehicleID = tempVehicle.VehicleID Then
                Await UpdateVehicleStats(tempVehicle)
            End If
        Next

        Return True
    End Function
```

The code I am trying to start the task doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to provide the parameter.  I get an error that "Task(Of Boolean) cannot be converted to System.Action and or an error on the parameter"

```
    Dim tempTask As Task
    tempTask = New Task(UpdateVehicleSummaries(tempVehicleID))
    tempTask.Start()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UpdateVehicleSummaries` is already asynchronous, you should be abel to just do:

```
Dim tempTask As Task(Of Boolean) = UpdateVehicleSummaries(tempVehicleID)
```

The returned `Task(Of T)` will be "hot" (running), but shouldn't block, as the `Await` call will immediately return control flow to the caller at that point.

---

A more typical use of this method, if you need to perform other work while this runs, would be to do the following:

```
Dim tempTask = UpdateVehicleSummaries(tempVehicleID)

' Do your other work

Dim success = Await tempTask ' Get the boolean result asynchronously...

' use the result
```

Comment: So use would be something similar to this?:   Dim tempTask As Task(Of Boolean) = UpdateVehicleSummaries(tempVehicleID)  
  'do other stuff   
  tempTask.Wait()   
  'continue work

Comment: @RobertBeaubien Normally, you'd use await in there instead.  That avoids ever needing to call `Wait()` - though you can if you want/need to do so

Comment: @RobertBeaubien Just added more typical use example ;)